# Django - How can you include annotated results in a serialized QuerySet?

Tags: python, json, django, annotate, serialization

How can you include annotated results in a serialized QuerySet?

```
data = serializer.serialize(Books.objects.filter(publisher__id=id).annotate(num_books=Count('related_books')), use_natural_keys=True)
```

However the key/value pare {'num_books': number} is not include into the json result.

I've been searching for similar questions on the internet, but i didn't found a solution that worked for me.

Here is a similar case: http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/How-can-you-include-annotated-results-in-a-serialized-QuerySet-td67238.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I did some research and found that `serializer.serialize` can only serialize queryset, and annotation just adds an attribute with each object of the queryset, so when you try to serialize a query, annotated fields aren't shown. This is my way of implementation:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

books = Books.objects.filter(publisher__id=id).annotate(num_books=Count('related_books')).values()
json_data = json.dumps(list(books), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Answer (score 10):

As shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122016/why-wont-serialize-capture-annotate-fields) you can use SerializerMethodField in your Serializer:

```py
class BooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  num_books = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_num_books(self, obj):
    try:
        return obj.num_books
    except:
        return None
```

It will serialize the annotated value (readonly)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer it works perfectly!

Comment: This is the correct answer. AIt is also possible to do the same annotation logic in the `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` method, however not preferable if already done on `queryset` to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: There is no ModelSerializer class in Django.

Comment: I meant drf's ModelSerializer https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link, [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5711) has been solved by pull request (https://github.com/django/django/pull/1176) some months ago.

You need to add `num_books` as a property:

```
class Publisher():
    ....

    @property
    def num_books(self):
        return some_way_to_count('related_books')
```

and then call it like so:

```
data = serializer.serialize(Books.objects.filter(publisher__id=id)), use_natural_keys=True, extra=['num_books'])
```

I'm not too sure about the exact syntax, since I don't work much with serializers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i can't make it work. Also, if my Model is the Django built in User (`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`) how do you do it?

Comment: As of October 2017, the pull request has been closed without being merged, and the ticket is still open.

Answer (score -1):

To get count from specific columns, you must declare them via `values` method

```
>>>> Books.objects.filter(publisher__id=id).values('<group by field>').annotate(num_books=Count('related_books'))
[{'num_books': 1, '<group by field>': X}]
```

Comment: The count that i make is correct, the problem is the serializer class. But thanks for the help!