# Queryset Serialize: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to pass a `queryset` as a `JSON` object:

`structure=Fund.objects.all().values('structure').annotate(total=Count('structure')).order_by('-total')`

However, `querysets` aren't `Json Serializable` therefore, I modified my code:

```
from django.core import serializers


structure=serializers.serialize('json',Fund.objects.all().values('structure').annotate(total=Count('structure')).order_by('-total'))
```

But I get this error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'` and this is my queryset: `<QuerySet [{'total': 106, 'structure': 'Corp'}, {'total': 43, 'structure': 'Trust'}, {'total': 2, 'structure': 'OM'}, {'total': 0, 'structure': None}]>`

Comment: Anser here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061105/1571826

Comment: tried it already, using `only` didn't work.

Comment: Try putting your query set (stripped down to the values dict) into a top level dictionary like {'thing': the_queryset} and serialize that object. Sometimes the serializer won't let you serialize a list-like thing because security.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - How can you include annotated results in a serialized QuerySet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401103/django-how-can-you-include-annotated-results-in-a-serialized-queryset)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django core serializers can only serialize a `queryset`. But `values()` doesn't return `queryset`, rather a `ValuesQuerySet` object. You can specifiy the fields you wish to use in `values()` in the `serialize()` method as follows:

```
from django.core import serializers

funds = Fund.objects.all().annotate(total=Count('structure')).order_by('-total')
structure = serializers.serialize('json', funds, fields=('structure',))
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get values related to a fk? for example userID__username, how would I do this using the fields=() ?

Comment: @dantheman I'm adding this comment for anyone who stumbles upon this issue like I did. This is the proper way to do it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/#natural-keys

Answer (score 6):

you can try it:

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

qs = Fund.objects.values('structure').annotate(
    total=Count('structure')
).order_by('-total')
structure = json.dumps(list(qs), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```