# Django: Add a list to a QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I am new to django so apologies if this is not possible or easy.

I have a view that takes a subset of a model

```
data = Terms.objects.filter(language = language_id)
```

The subset is one language. The set has a number of concepts for a language. Some languages might use the same word for multiple concepts, and I want to colour these the same in an SVG image. So I do this next:

```
for d in data:
    if d.term is None:
        d.colour = "#D3D3D3"
    else:
        d.colour = termColours[d.term]
```

Where termColours is a dictionary with keys as the unique terms and values as the hexadecimal colour I want.

I thought this would add a new colour attribute to my queryset. However, when I convert the queryset to json (in order to pass it to JS) the colour object is not there.

```
    terms_json = serializers.serialize('json', data)
```

How can I add a new colour element to my queryset?

Comment: Could you explain why this would help?

Comment: .values() will turn your queryset into a list of dictionaries. As such, they can be modified as you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your Queryset to Dict and then modify values.

**Ex:**

```
data = Terms.objects.filter(language = language_id).values()
for d in data:
    if d.term is None:
        d.colour = "#D3D3D3"
    else:
        d.colour = termColours[d.term]
```

Comment: This breaks the serialisation line with
"AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'"

Comment: This should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062242/queryset-serialize-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-meta

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you need [Django ORM annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate). And it might look like that:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value

data = Terms.objects.filter(language = language_id)
                     .annotate(color = Case(
                               When(term__isnull = True, then = "#D3D3D3"),
                               When(term__isnull = False, then = termColours[Value(term)]),))
```

Only problem here - I don't exactly know this moment - `termColours[Value(term)]`, you need to test different combinations of that [expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) to get the value of field `term`.