# Why won't serialize capture annotate fields?

Tags: django, geojson, annotate

I had no idea adding data to a queryset would be so hard. It's like, if it didn't come directly from the db then it might as well not exist. Even when I annotate, the new fields are 2nd class citizens and aren't always available.

Why won't serialize capture my annotate fields?

> Model

```
class Parc(models.Model):
    # Regular Django fields corresponding to the attributes in the
    # world borders shapefile.
    prop_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)  # OBJECTID: Integer (10.0)
    shp_id = models.IntegerField()

    # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField)
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=2277)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    floorplan_area = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    price_per_area = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    nbhd = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    # Returns the string representation of the model.
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return str(self.shp_id)
```

> Query:

```
parcels = Parc.objects\
    .filter(prop_id__in=attrList)\
    .order_by('prop_id') \
    .annotate(avg_price=Avg('sale_price'),
              perc_90_price=RawAnnotation('percentile_disc(%s) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sale_price)', (0.9,)),
              )
geojson = serialize('geojson', parcels)
```

When I print geojson it has no key/values for avg_price or perc_90_price. At this point, I'm leaning towards creating a dummy field and then populating it with the my customer calculations after I retrieve the queryset but I'm open to ideas.

[Helper class](https://medium.com/squad-engineering/hack-django-orm-to-calculate-median-and-percentiles-or-make-annotations-great-again-23d24c62a7d0)

```
class RawAnnotation(RawSQL):
"""
RawSQL also aggregates the SQL to the `group by` clause which defeats the purpose of adding it to an Annotation.
"""
def get_group_by_cols(self):
    return []
```

Comment: What does the `serialize()` exactly do?

Comment: Takes a queryset and turns it into JSON. Specifically, in this case geojson but it ignores the annotate fields. I think i'm going to try and turn the serialized string back into JSON structure, modify it, and then re-serialize.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25420323/7491209 seems annotations will not appear while serializing.

Comment: I ended up turning the serialized string back into a true json object, modifying the properties' subdict, and then re-serializing.

Answer (score 7):

I use annotations with Django Rest Framework and the Serializers in that library.

In particular, the serializer method allows you to access the query set. You can do something like this.

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  avg_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_avg_price(self, obj):
    try:
        return obj.avg_price
    except:
        return None
```

As mentioned by Carl Kroeger Ihl, you can also use:

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
   avg_price = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True)
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: Just tested it and it works, exactly what I needed too.

Comment: You could also use `avg_price = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True)` and not need the `get_avg_price` function