# Add a virtual field to a django query

Tags: python, django

I want to add an extra field to a query set in Django.

The field does not exist in the model but I want to add it to the query set.

Basically I want to add an extra field called "upcoming" which should return "True"

I already tried adding a @property method to my model class. This does not work because apparently django queries access the DB directly.

models.py

```
class upcomingActivity(models.Model):
    title      = models.CharField  (max_length=150)
    address    = models.CharField  (max_length=150)
```

Views.py

```
def get(self, request):
    query = upcomingActivity.objects.all()
    feature_collection = serialize('geojson', query ,
                                    geometry_field='location',
                                    fields= ( 'upcoming','title','address','pk' ) 
                                    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is for the case that you do not want to add a virtual property to the model (the model remains as is).

To add an additional field to the queryset result objects:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Value

upcomingActivity.objects.annotate(upcoming=Value(True, output_field=BooleanField())).all()
```

Each object in the resulting queryset will have the attribute `upcoming` with the boolean value `True`.
(Performance should be nice because this is easy work for the DB, and Django/Python does not need to do much additional work.)

EDIT after comment by Juan Carlos:

The Django serializer is for serializing model objects and thus will not serialize any non-model fields by default (because basically, the serializer in this case is for loading/dumping DB data).

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/

> Django’s serialization framework provides a mechanism for “translating” Django models into other formats.

See also: [Django - How can you include annotated results in a serialized QuerySet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401103/django-how-can-you-include-annotated-results-in-a-serialized-queryset)

---

From my own experience:

In most cases, we are using `json.dumps` for serialization in views and this works like a charm. You can prepare the data very flexibly for whatever needs arize, either by annotations or by processing the data (list comprehension etc.) before dumping it via `json`.

---

Another possibility in your situation could be to customize the serializer or the input to the serializer after fetching the data from the DB.

Comment: this is the correct answer to the question asked. However I discovered that the serializer will not read the extra field. As @Risadinha suggested a custom serializer would be needed to add a custom field to a django serializer.

Comment: @JuanCarlos you are right. I've added this info and a link to another SO question about that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class function to return the `upcoming` value like this:

```
def upcoming(self):
    is_upcoming = # some logic query or just basically set it to true. 
    return is_upcoming
```

then call it normally in your serializer the way you did it.

```
fields= ( 'upcoming','title','address','pk' )
```